# JRuby issues creating Java type cast float array

Tags: jruby, pdfbox

I'm using `jruby-9.2.6.0` to import a Java pdf library. `PDColor` is a class that becomes instantiated with an array of floats as well as a string constant. The **[Java example code that I'm referencing](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java)** looks like the following:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;

PDColor componentColor = new PDColor(new float[]{1, 0, 0}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
```

In `jruby`, my code looks like the following:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;

float_arr = [1.to_f, 0.to_f, 0.to_f]
componentColor = PDColor.new(float_arr, PDDeviceRGB::INSTANCE)
```

The issue is, it seems that the `float_arr` param is not typed as a float array, and thus we get the following error:

```
NameError (no constructor for arguments (org.jruby.RubyArray,org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB) on Java::OrgApachePdfboxPdmodelGraphicsColor::PDColor)
  available overloads:
    (org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray,org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorSpace)
    (org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName,org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorSpace)
    (float[],org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorSpace)
```

Is there a known way in `jruby` to convert a Ruby array of floats into a Java float array?

Comment: Accoding to https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby this should work: `[1, 2, 3.5].to_java Java::float` thus you should do `float_arr.to_java Java::float`. But I know nothing about jruby LOL

Comment: Note that you posted the same question twice. The link on the now deleted question was pointing to this question

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for the heads up, I just realized after your comment on the other one - I had a couple errors from Stack Overflow during the initial post - the question was probably created server-side but my particular client errored out. I deleted the duplicate after realizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [@TilmanHausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr), the constructor expects a Java array of [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) floats. To create it, you can call [`Array#to_java(:float)`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby).

Here's a small program to test this behavior. [`pdfbox-2.0.15.jar`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x) should be in the same folder as the script, which should be run with `jruby`:

```rb
require './pdfbox-2.0.15.jar'
java_import 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor'
java_import 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB'
red = PDColor.new([1.0, 0, 0].to_java(:float), PDDeviceRGB::INSTANCE)
puts red
#=> PDColor{components=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], patternName=null}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it makes sense to me logically. For some odd reason, despite this returning `java.lang.Float[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` in `jruby`, which to me looks right, it did not work for the library constructor despite it fulfilling one of the constructor definitions on their [docs](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.7/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/color/PDColor.html)

Comment: What happened? There are a lot of occurences in the software where that constructor is used.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Got the same `NameError: no constructor arguments for PDDeviceRGB` as the one in my question

Comment: Very weird… you could try this: after creating the PDColor with the working constructor, call `color.getComponents()`. This is a float array. If you can't pass that one to another new constructor, then it means there is a bug in that JRuby thing. Btw make sure you're using the latest PDFBox version (2.0.15).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr That indeed produces a float array, and it satisfies the `PDColor` constructor. From my console, there's a distinction between the float array received from `.getComponents()` output, and the one produced in this particular answer. `color.getComponents` produced `float[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]@243c4346` while `[1, 0, 0].to_java(java.lang.Float)` produces `java.lang.Float[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]@5d08976a` which seem to be different object types

Comment: Oh I got it. `float` is the primitive type (which is needed), and `Float` is the object type. These are not the same in java. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr shoot, you're right. Ill modify it asap. I cannot seem to find a way to delete the answer on my smartphone. Thanks a lot for the investigation! Feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: I won't write one, I don't know anything about JRuby, only pdfbox. Take your time. I just want a better answer than the accepted one - that one is correct and fine, but too complex IMHO.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: Updated & tested! Thank you very much for your help, and sorry for the wrong answer.

Comment: @Xenyal: Sorry, my original answer was wrong. The updated one seems to work.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr that's indeed the case, thanks for the analysis and thank you EricDuminil for updating your answer!